# Wampserver Configuration with SQL Server 2017

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp, wampserver

Hello to anyone reading this. I am having a serious issue with configuration using Wampserver & SQL Server 2017. The PHP version is 7.1.9. Apache 2.4.27.  The inspiration I have received was from a video made a few years ago https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUUh_WVzqq4 . All I am trying to do at this point is simply set up the connection to the database locally. I posted my php code and this is the error that I am getting outputted to browser...

```
Connection could not be established.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-REPGNI2$'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-REPGNI2$'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4060 [code] => 4060 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "officialdatabase" requested by the login. The login failed. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "officialdatabase" requested by the login. The login failed. ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-REPGNI2$'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-REPGNI2$'. ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4060 [code] => 4060 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "officialdatabase" requested by the login. The login failed. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "officialdatabase" requested by the login. The login failed. ) )
```

It seems to be a common error based on what I have been looking up about it. I have tried updating my drivers to the newest version **ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server** *TO* **ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server**. I have the dll files in the php.ini located in Apache (I think) and as proof see the phpinfo() [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AppQ.png). These dll files are the ones for version 7.0+ for PHP by the way. The service is running under a name "NT Service\MSSQLSERVER" and I have tried changing this to a true user in my database which is just me under the Windows Authentication (In SQL Server my Windows Authentication has privileges as well to the database). I have also tried filling in the "UID" and "PWD" fields in my connectionInfo with a user that I created as an admin. I have tried re-downloading Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x64) - 12.0.30501. All of this has resulted in no success and the same error. Any idea what the problem could be?

```
<?php
$serverName = "Desktop-repgni2"; //serverName\instanceName

// Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
// The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"officialdatabase");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Comment: `Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-REPGNI2$`

Comment: Hmmmm. I actually don't have a db_admin with this name? Should I go ahead and create one. Also should i reconfigure sql server configuration manager to run under this new account?